# Даны 2 текста. Вывести совпадающие в этих текстах слова. Pascal

Tags: pascal

Нужно для университета. Никак не получается сделать самому. Вот код, который я набросал:

```
Const
  separators = [' ' , ',','.',';',':'];
Var str1,str2 : string;
    cur_word : string;
    a1 : array [1..1000] of string;
    a2 : array [1..1000] of string;
    i : integer;
    el : integer;
    n : integer;
Begin
  Writeln('Введите первую строку: ');
  Readln(str1);
  Writeln('Введите вторую строку: ');
  Readln(str2);
  i := 1;
 // Сохранение всех слов в массив а1
    While not(i <= length(str1)) do
     Begin
while (str[el] in separators) do
  Begin
    cur_word := cur_word + 1;
    el := el + 1;
  end;
  // Если конец слова
  if str1[el + 1] in separators then
  // Запись слова в массив
    for el := 1 to n do
      a1[el + 1] := cur_word;
    i := i + 1;
End;
 // Сохранение всех слов в массив а2
 i := 1;
 While not(str2[i + 1] in separators ) do //and (i<=length(str2))
Begin
  cur_word := cur_word + 1;
  i := i + 1;
  Writeln(i);
  if str2[i + 1] in separators then
    for el := 1 to n do
      a1[el + 1] := cur_word;

End; 
Writeln(a1);
Writeln(a2);
```

end.

Answer (score 1):

А свой код хотя бы компилировать пробовал?) В паскале нельзя вывести массив прямым способом через writeln. Нужно в цикле пройтись по всем элементам массива и вывести их поочередно. А ещё в 21 строке ты складываешь строку с числом. Любой компилятор бы выдал ошибку.

Вот рабочая программа, успехов в дальнейшем изучении!

```
Program pr1;
Const
    seperators = ['.', ',', ':', ' ', ';', '!', '?', '-', '"'];
Var
    str1, str2, helper: string; // Первая, вторая и воспомогательная строка
    i, j: integer; // Переменные циклов
    el1, el2, el3: integer; // Число элементов первого, второго и результирующего массивов
    a1, a2, res: array[1..1000] of string; // Первый, второй и результирующий массивы слов
Begin
    str1:= 'Привет, мир!';
    str2:= 'Он подошёл ко мне и сказал "Привет!"';
    
    // Прибавляем к концу каждой строки разделитель, чтобы учесть последнее слово
    str1:= str1 + ' ';
    str2:= str2 + ' ';
    
    el1:= 0;
    helper:= '';
    for i:= 1 to length(str1) do // Проходим по элементам 1-й строки
    begin
        if not (str1[i] in seperators) then // Если текущий симовл - не разделитель
            helper:= helper + str1[i] // Записываем его в воспомогательную строку
        else
        begin
            if (helper <> '') then // Иначе, если воспомогательная строка не пустая (т.е в ней содержится какое-то слово)
            begin
                el1:= el1 + 1; // Увеличиваем число используемых элементов первого массива
                a1[el1]:= helper; // Записываем слово в первый массив
                helper:= ''; // Обнуляем воспомогательную строку
            end;     
        end;
    end;
    
    // Тут всё аналогично с предыдущим циклом, но для 2-й строки
    el2:= 0;
    helper:= '';
    for i:= 1 to length(str2) do
    begin
        if not (str2[i] in seperators) then
            helper:= helper + str2[i]
        else
        begin
            if (helper <> '') then
            begin
                el2:= el2 + 1;
                a2[el2]:= helper;
                helper:= '';
            end;     
        end;
    end;
    
    el3:= 0;
    for i:= 1 to el1 do // Проходим по всем словам из первой строки
        for j:= 1 to el2 do // Проходим по всем словам из второй строки
            if a1[i] = a2[j] then // Если есть совпадение
            begin
                el3:= el3 + 1; // Увеличиваем число элементов результирующего массива
                res[el3]:= a1[i]; // Записываем это слово в результирующий массив
            end;
    
    for i:= 1 to el3 do // Выводим массив
        writeln(res[i]);

End.
```